# Не срабатывает код при добавлении <div> ...</div>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

изучаю Python, остановился на парсинге сайта, написал простую .html страницу вот часть кода:

```html
...
    <div class='user__name' id='aaa'> 
        <span>Djem</span>  <br>
    </div>
    <div class='user__birth__date'
        <span> Date of birthday </span>
        <span> 02.07.89 </span>
    </div>
...
```

при этом коде парсер срабатывает и выдает нужное значение, но если добавляю еще один элемент div:

```html
    <div class='user__info'>
      <div class='user__name' id='aaa'> 
            <span>Djem</span>  <br>
        </div>
        <div class='user__birth__date'
            <span> Date of birthday </span>
            <span>02.07.89 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

то код на Python:

```
...
    user_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'user__name', 'id':'aaa'}).find('span').text
    print(user_name)
```

Не срабатывает, по ошибке nonetype' object has no attribute 'text'

Понимаю вопрос простой, но хочу понять суть проблемы

Благодарю за ответ

Comment: `<div class='user__birth__date'` тут скобку не закрыли

Comment: Кроме того, каким парсером разбираете? Понимаю, что bs4, но что в него передаете? С `html.parser` у меня разобралось и вывело `Djem`

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, вывелось верно, передаю значение user_name

Comment: <div class='user__birth__date' тут скобку не закрыли, -чиорт побери(с), благодарю, причина оказалась тривиальной невнимательность)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал `html.parser` и находит с `find`, и через `select` (css-селектором):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text = """
    <div class='user__info'>
      <div class='user__name' id='aaa'> 
            <span>Djem</span>  <br>
        </div>
        <div class='user__birth__date'
            <span> Date of birthday </span>
            <span class='value'> 02.07.89 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
user_name = soup.find('div', {'class': 'user__name', 'id': 'aaa'}).find('span').text
print(user_name)
# Djem

user_name = soup.select_one('#aaa > span').text
print(user_name)
# Djem
```

Еще пример:

```
birth__date = soup.select_one('.user__info > .user__birth__date > .value').text.strip()
print(birth__date)
# 02.07.89

# По номеру элемента (при незакрытой скобке в user__birth__date элемент <span> Date of birthday </span> будет частью div, поэтому номер 1, если починить скобку, то будет номер 2)
birth__date = soup.select_one('.user__info > .user__birth__date > span:nth-child(1)').text.strip()
print(birth__date)
# 02.07.89
```